# How to hide android soft keypad when home key pressed

Tags: android

I have an activity in which has an EditText, when i press the "switch" on the keypad to switch input method, then popup a dialog(an input method list). Now press the home key, desktop will show but keypad and popued up dialog still dislays on top of the desktop, so how can i hide the keypad and popued up dialog when i press the home key?
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use:

```
// hiding keyboard
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(password.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

`password` is an `EditText` reference

Comment: Thank you, but not solved my problem, i want to hide the keypad and a popup dialog(related to keypad) when homekey pressed.

Comment: You are showing AlertDialog with something like `.show()`
so simply do `.hide()`